# Avoid double entry in SELECT query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

How to avoid multiple records to be listed on following query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT application_forms.date_submitted, 
                application_forms.application_type, 
                application_forms.online_offline2, 
                application_forms.decision, 
                application_forms.id, 
                notes.post_by_id 
FROM    application_forms 
             LEFT  JOIN notes 
                 ON  notes.user_id = application_forms.id
```

I would like to have 1 record listed not duplicates

Comment: So what are you getting? How does it differ from what you're expecting? Is it not selecting records with distinct values? What do the tables look like?

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to whole row, not just by single column. What doyou really want to do? can youshow us your recordsand your desired result?

Comment: I would like to list all records from application_form and depending on 2nd table notes, display different image. So lets say that note is added by Agent then image is orange , once another note is added my Admin image is Green, when no notes Image is BLACK, so far it work like Black image on beginning is working, Orange image is working as well, but once Admin add note then I have 2 records listed from application _form, 1 is showing green and other orange image, it always should be last note inserted for specific record

Comment: table application_forms got bookings and table notes got notes (multiple notes per booking) plus in application_forms.id = Unique ID AND notes.user_id = id connecting application_forms with notes

Comment: I should have 1 booking and image changed each time someone add note (depending on USER: Admin, Agent, No Notes)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT      application_forms.date_submitted, 
            application_forms.application_type, 
            application_forms.online_offline2, 
            application_forms.decision, 
            application_forms.id, 
            n.post_by_id 
FROM    application_forms 
         LEFT  JOIN (SELECT user_id , MAX(id) , notes.post_by_id FROM notes) as n
             ON  n.user_id = application_forms.id  
GROUP BY application_forms.date_submitted
```

See in the left join MAX(id) chooses the very last record of each note and joins it to the outer query row

Comment: well quear is more complicated I have only listed part of it

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT application_forms.date_submitted, application_forms.online_offline, application_forms.comp_by_app, application_forms.notes, application_forms.online_offline2, application_forms.decision, application_forms.id, notes.post_by_id FROM application_forms LEFT  JOIN notes ON  notes.user_id = application_forms.id   WHERE {$NXTFilter_rsapplication_forms1} AND  application_forms.user_id = %s and (application_forms.archivea is null or application_forms.archivea != 1) ORDER BY {$NXTSort_rsapplication_forms1}", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsapplication_forms1, "int"

Comment: what ever it is in the left join using max will do the trick for you now it is up to you how you can use it according to your requirements

Comment: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1=1 AND application_forms.user_id = 158 and (application_forms.archivea i' at line 4

Comment: Man it is only en example since i dont know exactly the structure of your db table. you can use primary key of your table in MAX()

Comment: but id is a primary key in application_forms

Comment: what is the primary key of your table notes?

Comment: nope: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1=1 AND application_forms.user_id = 158 and (application_forms.archivea i' at line 3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15501/discussion-between-raheel-shan-and-user974435)

Comment: once removed : GROUP BY application_forms.date_submitted , it's working no erros, let me test it now